# How can i check if a user has verified their email using a Auth0 endpoint

Tags: auth0, android-mvvm

I am currently working on a client project that requires authentication. They are using Auth0 for authenticating a user. The problem that I encountered is that I have to make an API call to Auth0 with userID to see if they verified their email or not. I have to continuously check whether they verified their email to allow them to proceed through the application. Im not sure how to approach this, do I create suspend function that checks every 10 seconds? If anyone has an example or method for this approach please let me know, thank you